# How to populate a django Model FormSet with Model instances AND default field values

Tags: django, formset

The problem is how to populate each form of a Model Formset using a queryset, and also providing initial data to the unbound forms in the formset.  Why?  I have a model called Answer.  I want to create many Answers to a Question model, and each Question is within a Section, another model.  When in the question detail page, I already know the Section and the Question the Answer object should belong to, and these will eventually just be rendered as hidden fields, but I need them in order to save the Answer object.

My models (reduced to the essential fields):

```py
class Section(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question


class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default='')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

My form:

```py
class AddAnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['answer', 'question', 'section']
```

I want to do this with Model Formsets since the user should be able to keep adding answers, and also edit answers previously given.  I've looked at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), which for django are excellent, and found how to add initial data [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#id2).  Initially, the template was displaying ALL Answer objects, which I saw is done by default, until I see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-custom-queryset) on how to use a queryset to limit the results.  Then tried to use

`initial={'section': section, 'question': question}`

Which created a `KeyError`

So how do I provide default values to `section` and `question` to each answer in the formset, while at the same time populate the bound formset forms with previously saved Answer objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, which is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/) and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), with quite a bit of searching and trying things out turns out to be quite simple.  For me, it ended up being putting initial in [ ]!

views.py

```py
    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AddAnswerForm)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST or None, 
                            initial=[{'section': section, 'question': question}], 
                            queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question=question))

    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return redirect('question', question.pk, question.question)
```

Now it works fine, but if the question was a duplicate, or if there is a better method, I would appreciate the feedback.  After struggling for hours, I thought it would be useful for others in a similar situation.

**EDIT**
I was so consumed with model formsets, that I did not read the docs on what they are based on, [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/)!  All the relevant information is there.  Moral of the story.  *Read the docs!*